# Searching a partial domain name

Tags: support, search

Partial word searches works fine except if the word you are searching is part of a domain name.

I searched for [pmanswers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=pmanswers), got 0 results. However, searching for [www.pmanswers.co.uk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=www.pmanswers.co.uk) gave 1 result (which was expected).

Is this a bug or did I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.` dots confuse the stemmer, I'd say. Use wildcards: [`*pmanswers*`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=*pmanswers*) works.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that the "*" works on the search.

Comment: Woops. Sorry - the colon was throwing me off.

Comment: The `:` colons confuse the editor, I'd say.